# Dehumidifier and spray water effect on curing concrete basement patch

Tags: concrete, dehumidifier

Internal trench waterproof system just installed in basement that includes some new concrete in July. Will a dehumidifier hinder optimal curing of the concrete and for how long? Also should I spray the new concrete with water every day to cure stonger?

Answer (score 1):

Humidity usually helps prevent the rapid drying of the concrete and prevent premature cracks on the concrete surface. However, a household dehumidifier would not have the power to dry the air to the extent that harms the fresh concrete, so I wouldn't worry about running a humidifier to keep household humidity low. But water curing is a good idea, depending on the thickness of the concrete and the weather, it usually requires 3 - 7 days.

Instead of water curing (could be undesirable), a water-soluble curing compound applied after concreting can be considered, or simply cover the fresh concrete with plastic sheeting has been proven to be effective.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the instructions on the packaging. Most concrete recommend spraying water on it for a few days. Some just suggest covering the fresh concrete with a plastic drop cloth for a few days. Some just say to let it dry and be done with it. If this was poured by a company and no instructions are available, go with the spraying

I wouldn't worry about a humidifier affecting the drying but if it helps you sleep at night, cover the concrete with the dropcloth.